# "Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm getting this note in the build whenever I do an inject into a kotlin class (btw, I have a mixed android project with both kotlin and java).

For example, after this gradle task: `compileStagingDebugJavaWithJavac` (StagingDebug is my build variant), I get this message:

> "Note: Generating a MembersInjector or Factory for com.packageNameXXX.CourseDiscoveryMapFragment. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead."

My **CourseDiscoveryMapFragment** code can be seen here:

```
class CourseDiscoveryMapFragment : Fragment(){

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: CourseDiscoveryMapPresenter

    lateinit var mapView: MapView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discovery_map, container, false)

        MapsInitializer.initialize(activity)

        mapView = view.mapView
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState?.getBundle(BUNDLE_KEY_MAP_STATE))

        (activity as BaseActivity)
                .activityComponent.inject(this)
}
```

And my **ActivityComponent** is :

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {

    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);

    void inject(CourseDiscoveryMapFragment fragment);

    //Exposed to sub-graphs.
    Activity activity();
}
```

So, I'm having dagger component and modules written in Java, while having dagger injections in Kotlin.

Is this anything that I should be worried about?

Thank you.

Comment: @JaysonMinard added more detail! sorry about it.

Comment: Hey, did you find solution or maybe reason for that warning?

Comment: No .. Still having those warnings. @wojciech_maciejewski

Comment: the same here, I dont have any idea why ....

Comment: I have the same warning. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: ditto...I'm puzzled by this as well.  The class is in the list of injectable classes, though in my case, it's an activity.

Comment: I'm getting this as well! Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the answer: https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/537

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437873/generating-a-membersinjector-for-class-prefer-to-run-the-dagger-processor-ove

Comment: The exact conditions to reproduce the message are given in one Dagger unit test: https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/666a546ee3e55fe3cc116a0cc993570bfd4f8c2d/compiler/src/test/java/dagger/internal/codegen/ComponentProcessorTest.java#L2320
However I still can't grasp what and why it happens !

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid you can't. Why not write dependency modules in Kotlin?

To write dependency modules in java, you need to configure your Gradle script in this way:

> ```
>  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
>  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
> ```

But, to write dependency modules in Kotlin, you should configure your Gradle script  in this way:

> ```
> compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8' 
> kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
> ```

dagger need the annotation processing tool to generate the dependency code during the compiling process. So I guess you just need to use the right APT(annotation processing tool) according to right language.