# Generating a MembersInjector for [Class]. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have these warnings and I don't understand what they mean. Can someone point me to something?

For classes I inject into (where there is a `component.inject(this)` statement)

```
Note: Generating a MembersInjector for [class] Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
```

For object I am injecting (constuctor annotated with `@Inject`)

```
Note: Generating a Provider for [class]. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
```

Comment: Do those classes extend some parent class, that has `@Inject` annotated fields or similar? have a look here https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/d80bc2a987f6efa3c1614cb93277d93bce8f6561/compiler/src/test/java/dagger/internal/codegen/ComponentProcessorTest.java

Comment: I have the same issue when injecting dependencies into a class which has a base class also contain `@Inject` annotated fields. I have not yet found a solution to get rid of this warning. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396307/getting-rid-of-dagger-2-warning-generating-a-membersinjector.

Answer (score 6):

When Dagger's annotation processor runs, it generates two types of classes:

1. Implementations of `@Component` interfaces
2. `Provider` and `MembersInjector` implementations for each `@Inject`'d type.

While it's generating the `@Component` interface implementation, it connects each of the `Provider` and `MembersInjector` implementations according to how your modules were configured.  If your component or any of the modules therein refer to an `@Inject`'d type that was compiled *without* the Dagger processor it will still generate the `Provider` or `MembersInjector`, but once for each component rather than once for the `@Inject`'d class.

This isn't *really* a problem (hence not a warning or error), but it does mean that can potentially have the Dagger processor generate the same classes many times for a single application.  It might slow down compilation if and take up a bit more bytecode if it really gets out of hand.

The easy fix is just to make sure that you're running the Dagger annotation processor when you compile your `@Inject`'d types as well as your components.

Comment: and how you make sure you run Dagger annotation processor whey you compile your @Inject types?

Comment: Just by making sure that the annotation processor is on the classpath when you compile that type.

Comment: @gk5885 Could you provide a code example? I think the annotation processor is included in my classpath, but I'm still getting the warning.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to provide a code example of an invocation of javac that is any more meaningful than just saying that the dagger compiler should be on the classpath when you compile your `@Inject`ed types and `@Module`s.  If you believe that you are doing that, but are still getting the message, please file a bug.

Comment: it happen same case on my project, but it is not showing all of my component in this warning. so i found out that it will warning classes which have private fields. the warning is gone after i remove it or use Dagger to generate it.
i am not sure that is the root cause, just share my case. hope it is helpful. :-)

Comment: @gk5885 do you meant to add `classpath "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"` to project `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yeah, this answer is pretty obscure. No one here is compiling their Android project with `javac`.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this `"Generating a MembersInjector for..."` Dagger 2 warning when I had a superclass and subclass as follows...

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Actvity {

    @Inject
    DependencyA dependencyA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
}

public class ConcreteActivity extends BaseActvity {

    @Inject
    DependencyB dependencyB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

... and my `Component` interface had two inject methods as follows...

```
void inject(BaseActivity activity);
void inject(ConcreteActivity activity);
```

I removed the `inject(BaseActivity activity)` method from my `Component` interface and I removed the `Component.inject(this)` method call from the `BaseActivity` class. The injection in `BaseActivity` still works as expected when the subclass (`ConcreteActivity`) calls `Component.inject(this)` and I do not see the `"Generating a MembersInjector for..."` Dagger 2 warning anymore when I build the application.

Comment: Actually, my answer is not entirely correct. I have two apps for which I've made the above-described change. In one of the apps I no longer see the warning but in the other I do. I can't see any difference between the two apps in terms of how I've used Dagger 2 so I'm stumped at this point and out of ideas.